# Call a button on a C# form through usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I've created a user control with some buttons. When you click a button in the UserControl the BackColor of the button changes:

```
 private void button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
        switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
        {
            case "Crimson": ctrl.BackColor = Color.Blue; break;
            case "Green": ctrl.BackColor = Color.Orange; break;
            case "Orange": ctrl.BackColor = Color.Crimson; break;
            case "Blue": ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green; break;
            default: ctrl.BackColor = Color.Crimson; break;
        }
    }
```

on my form is another button which is enabled = false; 
so when the color in the UserControl changes I want the button on my form enabled=true;

Comment: Then you'd probably need to find a way to tell your form that the button in your user control has changed it's back color. Maybe creating a event in your user control and subscribing to it in your form?

Comment: you mean you are working in one form only?

Comment: i dont know how to do that

Comment: im working in one form only

Comment: and working two buttons with one has been set to default false

Comment: the buttons change the color already when hit click what is your problem

Comment: when the color changes i need to enable a button on form

Comment: but if the color doesn't change you mean the button remains enabled false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it like this;

control:

```
public delegate void ColorChangeEventHandler();

public partial class myControl: UserControl
{


    public event ColorChangeEventHandler ColorChanged;

    private void OnColorChange()
    {
        if(ColorChanged != null)
        {
            ColorChanged.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public speelRij()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnColorChange();
        Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
        switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
        {
            case "Crimson": ctrl.BackColor = Color.Blue; break;
            case "Green": ctrl.BackColor = Color.Orange; break;
            case "Orange": ctrl.BackColor = Color.Crimson; break;
            case "Blue": ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green; break;
            default: ctrl.BackColor = Color.Crimson; break;
        }
```

form:

```
 public myForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myControl1.ColorChanged += () => { Button1.Enabled = true;};
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `UserControl` make event handler `ColorChanged` and fire that event when color changes. In your form add listener and appropriate code when event fires.

So, in your control, make `EventHandler`, like this

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public EventHandler ColorChanged;
```

then, fire event on your button click, like this:

```
private void button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    //rest of your code...
}
```

in your form, add listener:

```
userControl.ColorChanged += new EventHandler(UserControl_ColorChanged)
```

and add method that will be executed and enable button...

```
private void UserControl_ColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //enable button here
}
```

Comment: userControl.ColorChanged += new EventHandler(UserControl_ColorChanged) this gives me error

Comment: @jellewoord what kind of error? userControl should be the name of your user control. I don't know how you named it...

Comment: @jellewoord i have edited my answer, forgot one thing. If you haven't tried this answer, try now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the parent form using this

```
Form parentFrm = (this.Parent as Form);
```

You can then access controls on the parent Form, by either making the public or finding the control by its name

```
 Button aButton = (Button)parentFrm.Controls["btnName"];
 if (aButton != null)
     aButton.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Although Ninos answer above is the prefered way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Event Aggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) and make the  button in user control will publish an event and make you window handle the event

Comment: OP question is about winforms